# Are there any API to turn on DXVA in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, macos-carbon

I wrote a video playback application based on Carbon in MAC OSX, are there any API to turn on the DXVA feature which support by Graphic Card? Does it support in QuickTime SDK or Carbon API?

Answer (score 0):

DirectX is part of Windows. It doesn't exist in Mac OS X.

If you're doing hardware-accelerated video playback: Why are you worrying about it? If the hardware supports it, chances are, the APIs will use it. So just play your movie and let the library take care of doing it through the graphics card or not.

If you're doing video capture: [Core Video](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/CoreVideo/) will let you do that through the graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that on very-recent hardware only, QuickTime will use hardware video acceleration for the decoding of some types of video stream.

Note that this is NOT specifically related to the capabilities of the graphics card, for example the 8800GT PureVideo feature works fine under Windows but is unused in OS X.